# keyup change is not triggering in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
j("input[name='textFriendEmail']").bind('keyup change',function (e){
                    var value = j(this).val();
                    j('#toEmail').val(value);
                });
```

js file contain this code but its not triggering. is something wrong with this code?

I tried to place this in seprate file and link to the page gain but no luck. pl help.

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup? Also, if you're using jQuery 1.7+ you should be using [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of .bind

Comment: Is this code inside `j(document).ready()`?

Comment: @Barmar no its not in j(document).ready

Comment: then that could be the problem... move it to dom ready... see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LpfuH/1/

Comment: @RGraham ok I am using jquery 1.10+ .on will do the same thins as .bind?

Comment: From the `.bind()` documentation: _As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document._

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your code in a DOM ready event. Since you're using jQuery 1.10, you should also replace your bind function with [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
j(function() {
    // This is only fired when the DOM is ready
    j(document).on("keyup change", "input[name='textFriendEmail']",function (e){
        // This is fired on keyup/change of the textFriendEmail input
        var value = j(this).val();
        j('#toEmail').val(value);
    });
});
```

From the jQuery docs:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. Check if its is wrapped in DOM ready function. It should be inside that.

```
j(document).ready(function(){
   j("input[name='textFriendEmail']").bind('keyup change',function (e){
                    var value = j(this).val();
                    console.log(value);
                    j('#toEmail').val(value);
                });
});
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kVNuj/

Answer (score 0):

```
j(document).ready(function(){
    j("input[name='textFriendEmail']").on('keyup change',function (e){
        var value = j(this).val();
        j('#toEmail').val(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: How will this help? All you did was change `bind` to `on`, but they're equivalent.

Comment: Sorry. I see I left out the j(document).ready wrapping. Updated now.